# Resize on div element

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery has the `resize()` - event, but it just work with window.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() { /* What ever */ });
```

This works fine! But when I want to add the event to a div element it doesn't work.

E.g.

```
jQuery('div').resize(function() { /* What ever */ });
```

I want to start an callback when the size of a div-element has changed. I don't want to start a resizable - event – just a event to check if the size of a div -
 element has changed.

Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: resize events are only fired on window(s) objects (and iframes maybe?).

Comment: have a look at this page - http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/

Comment: This might help: resizeObserver.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver.  Supported by Chrome 64, Firefox 69...

Answer (score 35):

`DIV` does not fire a `resize` event,  so you won't be able to do exactly what you've coded, but you could look into [monitoring DOM properties](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/).

If you are actually working with something like resizables, and that is the only way for a div to change in size, then your resize plugin will probably be implementing a callback of its own.

Comment: You can trigger the window resize event with $(window).trigger("resize");

Comment: the link [monitoring DOM properties](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/) please updated it

Answer (score 33):

I was only interested for a trigger when a width of an element was changed (I don' care about height), so I created a jquery event that does exactly that, using an invisible iframe element.

```
$.event.special.widthChanged = {
  remove: function() {
      $(this).children('iframe.width-changed').remove();
  },
  add: function () {
      var elm = $(this);
      var iframe = elm.children('iframe.width-changed');
      if (!iframe.length) {
          iframe = $('<iframe/>').addClass('width-changed').prependTo(this);
      }
      var oldWidth = elm.width();
      function elmResized() {
          var width = elm.width();
          if (oldWidth != width) {
              elm.trigger('widthChanged', [width, oldWidth]);
              oldWidth = width;
          }
      }

      var timer = 0;
      var ielm = iframe[0];
      (ielm.contentWindow || ielm).onresize = function() {
          clearTimeout(timer);
          timer = setTimeout(elmResized, 20);
      };
  }
}
```

It requires the following css :

```
iframe.width-changed {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You can see it in action here [widthChanged fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/333gu11u/)

Comment: This is the right answer. Attaching the event to an iframe's window is much less hacky than an interval.

Comment: This is perfect! I made mine completely js based by adding the stylesheet dynamically:

`var ss = document.createElement('style');
        ss.type = "text/css";
        ss.innerHTML = "iframe.width-changed {width: 100%;display: block;border: 0;height: 0;margin: 0;}";
        document.body.appendChild(ss);`

Comment: This is pure genius.

Comment: I'm about to use it but i wonder: what is the role of the  timer and the setTimeout ? is it like a "debounce"/throttle  to prevent too many resize to be detected when the user resize the element ?

Comment: Yes it is to prevent invoking too many times the "widthChanged" trigger

Comment: I've created jQuery.resize plugin https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.resize it use exactly the same technique (it triggers also on height), but it also use ResizeObserver if browser supports it.

Answer (score 21):

```
// this is a Jquery plugin function that fires an event when the size of an element is changed
// usage: $().sizeChanged(function(){})

(function ($) {

$.fn.sizeChanged = function (handleFunction) {
    var element = this;
    var lastWidth = element.width();
    var lastHeight = element.height();

    setInterval(function () {
        if (lastWidth === element.width()&&lastHeight === element.height())
            return;
        if (typeof (handleFunction) == 'function') {
            handleFunction({ width: lastWidth, height: lastHeight },
                           { width: element.width(), height: element.height() });
            lastWidth = element.width();
            lastHeight = element.height();
        }
    }, 100);


    return element;
};

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 8):

I've created jquery plugin [jquery.resize](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.resize) it use resizeObserver if supported or solution based on [marcj/css-element-queries](https://github.com/marcj/css-element-querie) scroll event, no setTimeout/setInterval.

You use just

```
 jQuery('div').on('resize', function() { /* What ever */ });
```

or as resizer plugin

```
jQuery('div').resizer(function() { /* What ever */ });
```

I've created this for jQuery Terminal and extracted into separated repo and npm package, but in a mean time I switched to hidden iframe because I had problems with resize if element was inside iframe. I may update the plugin accordingly. You can look at [iframe based resizer plugin in jQuery Terminal source code](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/blob/44b4febe232f42dedaa9ea0fda0258905d17075e/js/jquery.terminal-src.js#L743).

**EDIT**: new version use iframe and resize on it's window object because the previous solutions was not working when page was inside iframe.

**EDIT2**: Because the fallback use iframe you can't use it with form controls or images, you need to add it to the wrapper element.

**EDIT3:**: there is better solution using [resizeObserver polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resize-observer-polyfill) that use mutation observer (if resizeObserver is not supported) and work even in IE. It also have TypeScript typings.

Comment: That was a great idea. Good job, really.

Comment: Hurrah for EDIT3. I am forced to use IE11 and this did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is a really nice, easy to use, lightweight (uses native browser events for detection) plugin for both basic JavaScript and for jQuery that was released this year. It performs perfectly:

https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize

Comment: you said it doesn't poll constantly, but it does, it uses requestAnimationFrame : https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize/blob/master/detect-element-resize.js

Comment: Interesting: the referenced GitHub project was inspired by this blog post: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/ But the code in the post was significantly changed later, while the GitHub project seems to use the older approach. So it's worth to have a look at both before you decide what to use.

Answer (score 5):

There now exists [Resize Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

You could use it like so:

```
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(console.log);
})
resizeObserver.observe(document.getElementById("ExampleElement"));
```

Comment: This should be the right answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

what about this:

```
divH = divW = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    divW = jQuery("div").width();
    divH = jQuery("div").height();
});
function checkResize(){
    var w = jQuery("div").width();
    var h = jQuery("div").height();
    if (w != divW || h != divH) {
        /*what ever*/
        divH = h;
        divW = w;
    }
}
jQuery(window).resize(checkResize);
var timer = setInterval(checkResize, 1000);
```

BTW I suggest you to add an id to the div and change the $("div") to $("#yourid"), it's gonna be faster, and it won't break when later you add other divs

Comment: Of course - it was just an example - of course i use id's and classes to select my elements. I like your idea - i think it would work! Thanks a lot. I#ll try in a few minutes and will give a feedback.

Comment: This monitors the DIV for size changes whenever the window's `resize` event is fired. It is quite conceivable that the size of the div will change without being immediately followed by a window resize, in which case the `/* what ever */` part would not be evaluated.

Comment: Right! And this is the problem in my project. The div element is in an outer wrapper which has the css attribute Overflow:hidden - so the window doesnt change the size. But in other ways the example will work fine - i just tested it.

Comment: @Timo: `$(window).resize` listens to the act of physically resizing the browser window by, say, dragging the bottom right corner. There are no DOM events what so ever that trigger this event, `overflow:hidden` or not. This answer does not address your problem. It would make more sense to run this code in a timer, than attached to a random event listener that likely never will be triggered. It would be better still if you could use DOM property monitoring and fall back to a timer (or manually raising some event at the places where the div size can change).

Comment: added code for setInterval. You need to fine-tune it, 'cause 1000ms might be too much for you, on the other hand a too low numbercan easily kill your CPU. If you know that you don't need to listen any more then call: clearInterval(timer) !

Comment: Yes - it would. This is the way i just did it - but i dont like this solution. I dont know how the resize event works but setTimeout to recall a function any x seconds seems like a performance abatement.

Comment: that's why I used setInterval :)

Answer (score 2):

Only window is supported yes but you could use a plugin for it: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

Comment: No. this is exactly what OP tried, and pointed out that it doesn't work.

Comment: this use setTimeout which may be pretty expensive if you use this multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple implementation.

```html
    <script>
    var move = function(e) {
        if ((e.w && e.w !== e.offsetWidth) || (e.h && e.h !== e.offsetHeight)) {
            new Function(e.getAttribute('onresize')).call(e);
        }
        e.w = e.offsetWidth;
        e.h = e.offsetHeight;
    }
    var resize = function() {
        console.log('Resized')
    }
    </script>

    <style>
    .resizable {
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 200px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    </style>

    <div class='resizable' onresize="resize(this)" onmousemove="move(this)">
      Pure vanilla implementation
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a google maps integration I was looking for a way to detect when a div has changed in size. Since google maps always require proper dimensions e.g. width and height in order to render properly.

The solution I came up with is a delegation of an event, in my case a tab click. This could be a window resize of course, the idea remains the same:

```
if (parent.is(':visible')) {
    w = parent.outerWidth(false);
    h = w * mapRatio /*9/16*/;
    this.map.css({ width: w, height: h });
} else {
    this.map.closest('.tab').one('click', function() {
        this.activate();
    }.bind(this));
}
```

`this.map` in this case is my map div.
Since my parent is invisible on load, the computed width and height are 0 or don't match.
By using `.bind(this)` I can delegate the script execution (`this.activate`) to an event (`click`).

Now I'm confident the same applies for resize events.

```
$(window).one('resize', function() {
    this.div.css({ /*whatever*/ });
}.bind(this));
```

Hope it helps anyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your text or Content or Attribute depend on Screen size:
HTML:

```
<p class="change">Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)</p>
<p class="change">Frequently Asked Questions </p>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
const changeText = document.querySelector('.change');
function resize() {
  if((window.innerWidth<500)&&(changeText.textContent="Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)")){
    changeText.textContent="FAQ";
  } else {
    changeText.textContent="Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)";
  }
}
window.onresize = resize;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is("div")) {
    $("div").text("width: "+$("div").width());
  }
});
$("div").css({"width":"150px"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100px;transition-delay: 0.000000001s;">width: 100</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ A 'good answer' also includes a sentence or two in plain text that explains why you think your solution will work. Please visit SO Help Center and specifically this guideline for more details >>> stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to resize the div itself you need to specify that in css style. You need to add **overflow** and **resize property**.

Below is my code snippet

```
#div1 {
        width: 90%;
        height: 350px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        overflow: auto;
        resize: both;
    }

<div id="div1">

</div>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't apply to the original post. The broad discussion here is about listening for changes to the size of an element (and performing an action afterward), not setting the size of the element.