# How to fire event on general DOM object resize with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an event on window resize.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    ...
});
```

But what would it be if I want to fire the event on any type if DOM objects, like:

```
$('div#myDiv').resize(function() {
    ...
));
```

But the above seemed not work. Is this possible and convenient? Or any other good way?

Comment: Like this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086693/jquery-resize-on-div-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin offers the ability to create resize events based on an element:

> A Cross-Browser, Event-based, Element Resize Detection.
>
> In short, this implementation does NOT use an internal timer to detect
>   size changes (as most implementations I found do). It uses scroll
>   events on most browsers, and the onresize event on IE10 and below.
>
> The method used not only detects javascript generated resize changes
>   but also changes made from CSS pseudo classes e.g. :hover, CSS
>   animations, etc.

https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize

Comment: Thank you, may be what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible - but shouldn't really be necessary either. If your div is changing size based on the window size, i.e. via a media query, just use $(window).resize(). If it's changing via some other javascript code, you should just hook into that code.

If you wanted to, you could trigger a resize event on the div and listen to that, but you'd still be triggering the event manually - i.e.

```
$('div#myDiv').on('custom_resize', function() {
    ...
));

// whenever you change div size
$('div#myDiv').trigger('custom_resize');
```

If you don't have any access to the code changing the div, you could poll for changes in width/height - for example (just for width):

```
var div_width = $('div#myDiv').width();
setInterval(function() {
    if (div_width != $('div#myDiv').width()) {
        div_width = $('div#myDiv').width();
        $('div#myDiv').trigger('custom_resize');
    }
}, 1);
```

If you're adding an image dynamically, this should work:

```
$('<img>').on('load', function() { ... })
          .attr('src', {img url})
          .appendTo({container})
```

Comment: my problem is: there are several images in the div. when image load the div will change its size, I want it trigger then

Comment: Ah ok, in that case you should listen to the image's load event: `$('img').on('load', function() {...})`

Comment: But that's not too explicit to my problem: I want to trigger it after all images inside which were ready. But I don't want to care about what images are there and also, the `$('img').load()` seemed not triggering for every image.

Comment: So long as the images aren't dynamically added, you could try `$(window).on('load', ...)`?

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but when images were dynamic added, the solution still far from I desire.

Comment: `$('img').on('load', ...)` should work in that case - see updated answer