# jquery resize function on a specific element

Tags: jquery, resize

I want to be able to capture every change of size on a specific element.

I'm using this for my progress bar which is a `div`.

```
function appendPbar()
{
  var chbxArr = $(".checkbox input[type=checkbox]").not("[disabled]");
  var pbarWrapper = $('<span><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">0%</div></div></span>');

$(chbxArr).each(function(el){
    if (this.checked) 
    {
        $(this).parent().append(pbarWrapper);
    };
});

var pbar = $('.progress-bar');
pbar.resize(function()
        {
            console.log('sdf'); //this is not working
        });
return pbar;
}
```

I don't know how it works, need help.

Comment: correction..

var pbarWrapper = $('<span><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">0%</div></div></span>');

Comment: answered~"(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086693/jquery-resize-on-div-element)