# jQuery callback for element size change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a way to use a callback function after the screen is done resizing an element?

For example:

```
element.css('height', 'auto', function() {
   element.css('height', element.height() - 6);
});
```

In words: when the element is reset to it's default height. The DOM needs to re-evaluate the height of the element. That takes a bit of time, but that time varies from client to client. So I don't want to use a setTimeOut function and slow down the script much more then needed.

So how can I execute some JavaScript just after the element's height is reset?

PS: I already tried the jQuery animate function. But still that callback function doesn't seem to wait long enough for the element to actually obtain it's original height.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize on div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086693/resize-on-div-element)

Comment: Because there is text in a container that defines the height. The background of that container has a vertical repeating background that needs correction of -6 pixels. But the height of the container in total depends on the contents.

Comment: And NO that other post doesn't solve this problem!!! Bunch of haters. Can't post on this network anymore without instant downvotes.

Comment: Downvoters please give reason, do not demotivate someone.

Comment: Link provided by @Zenoo  has solution but in jQuery. Do you want solution in jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: jQuery or pure Javascript are both fine. But it would be nice to have a simple , short solution without the use of a plugin.

Comment: Downvotes are not supposed to demotivate someone, but to show them, that there is something wrong with the question. Downvotes don't change reputation if the question is deleted. I downvoted because this question already has an answer. And I really don't like it when someone asks the question that already has an answer. Because at least four people thinks that this question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086693/resize-on-div-element) it is not just my point of view.

Comment: That post doesn't solve this problem. It suggests plugins and setTimeOut functions as a "solution". I am asking for a solution to waiting on the element's DOM size change.

Comment: Elements doesn't have a DOM size event, the window does. Furthermore, you must have read this [mcve], and you still wonder why you get downvoted? FYI, I didn't downvote but I voted to close as it does not fulfill that requirement. We are note here to help write up code, we help with written code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even tough the comments weren't helpful at all. I found something that actually seems to work. It waits for the height change to process and instantly process the next rule afterwords.

```
element.css('height', 'auto').delay(1).css('height', element.height() - 6);
```