# Is there a way to notice, when <td> changes size?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I made an html table with cells, which have a resizable width, through CSS `resize`. My settings in CSS for `<td>` are:

```
td {
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 35px;
    min-width: 35px;
}
```

Now I want to know, if it is possible to notice, when the user changes the width. So, that I can do something, after the user changed it. Is there an event, when the user changes the width through CSS `resize`?

**EDIT**:
To hopefully reduce some confusion, I will give some more details about my end goal.

The end goal, which I try to achieve, is a table with fixed table head, scrollable table body and columns, which have a resizeable width (table head and table body synced).

So far I have achieved a table with a fixed head and scrollable body and a table with resizeable width columns separately, but not combined in one.

So, now I was trying to find a way of noticing, when a table cell of the head gets resized, so that I can adjust the width of the body cells in the same column (using JavaScript).

Comment: only through JS

Comment: I guess you did reset display on td or set tr as flex parent to allow overflow:auto on td elements. What is the purpose to watch on resize events here ? is it also to resize entire column or else ? ... just wondering why the td element

Comment: @TemaniAfif And how through JS? So far I haven't found a solution with JS either.

Comment: @G-Cyr I want to know, when the width has changed, so that I can adjust the width of a different element to the same value.

Comment: I understood that, but it seems weird applied to a td where the table-layout doesn't allow overflow to show a scroll.  `<table><tr><td>cell</td></tr></table>`  + your piece of CSS doesn't allow resize :(  You might be using a table for bad reasons ... not sure it's at the best and not bulletproof for sure ;)   what about IE or firefox users ?  test including js answer below  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyyrov  Maybe the whole thing/method is to be rethink :)

Comment: here is an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086693/resize-on-div-element#26077110 to a  similar question (no table involved) and its fiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/333gu11u/188/

Comment: Have you tried this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086693/resize-on-div-element

Comment: @G-Cyr Thanks for pointing me to the similar question. It helped me to figure out a workable solution.

Comment: This is not dupe of that jquery question. This is not a jquery question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments I was pointed to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26077110/9038475) from a similar question. It helped me to find a workable solution.

To create a widthChanged event:

```
$.event.special.widthChanged = {
    remove: function () {
        $(this).children('iframe.width-changed').remove();
    },
    add: function () {
        var elm = $(this);
        var iframe = elm.children('iframe.width-changed');
        if (!iframe.length) {
            iframe = $('<iframe/>').addClass('width-changed').prependTo(this);
        }
        var oldWidth = elm.width();
        function elmResized() {
            var width = elm.width();
            if (oldWidth != width) {
                elm.trigger('widthChanged', [width, oldWidth]);
                oldWidth = width;
            }
        }

        var timer = 0;
        var ielm = iframe[0];
        (ielm.contentWindow || ielm).onresize = function () {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(elmResized, 1);
        };
    }
}
```

And to use the event:

```
$('#id').on('widthChanged', function () {
    // Do what you want, when width changed
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the javascript onresize event, like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    document.getElementById('foo').style.color = 'red';
}) ;
```

```html
<span id="foo">Resize me</span>
```

Comment: I have tried that before. `onresize` only occurs, when the browser window is resized. That is not happening. The table cell gets resized through the user by pulling it apart or pushing it together. The window stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

There's the [`ResizeObserver` API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver) to solve this issue and there's [a polyfill](https://github.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill) for browsers that don't yet support it.

```js
const td = document.querySelector('.right');
const ro = new ResizeObserver((entries, observer) => {
    for (const entry of entries) {
        const {left, top, width, height} = entry.contentRect;

        console.log('Element:', entry.target);
        console.log(`Element's size: ${ width }px x ${ height }px`);
        console.log(`Element's paddings: ${ top }px ; ${ left }px`);
    }
});

ro.observe(td);

const leftElem = document.querySelector('.left');
setInterval(() => {
  leftElem.style.width = `${10 + Date.now() * 0.001 % 50 | 0}px`;
}, 100);
```

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
}
.left {
  background: red;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill/a3ae98bc/dist/ResizeObserver.global.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="left"></td>
    <td class="right"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```