# How to trigger event on width/height value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to figure out how to create an if statement if the width/ height is a certain value using this example.

https://codepen.io/Reklino/pen/EjKXqg

I was thinking of

```
<p id="confirmation">Try again!</p> 

 <script> 
  if (new dynamicSize.width() < 300) { 
    document.getElementById("confirmation").innerHTML = "Congratulations!"; 
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a more complete and specific example of your current code. The CodePen is too complex to identify the specific issue. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that codepen link is not in pure JS/Jquery, it is an angular code. 
If you want to do it in jQuery, something like this should work:

```
if ($(document).width() < 300){
  $('#confirmation').text('Congratulations!')
}
```

UPDATE: If you want to trigger each time the element is resized, check the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30761710/1817929

Comment: Thank you, I'm using Jquery now but how do I get the script to keep calling? It works on initial load but not if the element is resized

Comment: `$(window).on("resize")...`; no need to "keep calling".